# Keyboard does not disappear when tapping UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c

I have TableView. In each row i have textfield, three textfield have UIPickerView and two are editable, issue is when i tap on picker's textfield after tapping on editable textfield keyboard dosn't disappear here is the code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    tf_Selected = (UITextField*)textField;
    if ([textField.placeholder isEqualToString:@"Work Order "]) {
    if (dicWorkOrderNoData.count > 0) 
    {
        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Work Order" rows:[dicWorkOrderNoData   allValues] initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(selectPicker_ActionHandler:)  cancelAction:@selector(cancelSheet_ActionHandler) origin:textField];
    }
    else if (textField.tag == DateField_UptoCurrentDate)
    {
        [ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Date" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate  selectedDate:[NSDate date] maximumDate:[NSDate date] target:self action:@selector(selectDate_ActionHandler:) cancel:@selector(cancelSheet_ActionHandler) origin:textField];
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use : [textField resignFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[textField resignFirstResponder];`.

More on that [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @parilogic i use this in textFielsShouldReturn method but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It would better to assign to UITextField's inputAccessoryView Toolbar with [back, next, done] buttons, because you can't be sure that user actually selected pickerview's item or just scrolling them.

If you have few optionns, than use UIActionSheet instead.